# Casting from int to Enum still returning an int

Tags: c#, casting, enums

I am trying to cast from an int to an enum, unsuccessfully, as follows:

**ENUM**

```
public enum ePriceType{
    Fixed = 1,
    Variable = 2
}
```

**CAST**

```
public int priceTypeA = 2;
public ePriceType priceTypeB = (ePriceType)priceTypeA;
```

Code runs fine, but for some reason when you check the value of priceTypeB it still shows an `int` and not an `ePriceType` which causes an error further down the code.

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

In truth, this problem is a whole lot more complex involving the client side of a web service. I tried to simplify it as above but clearly didnt quite work and Im not sure how simplest to explain the full problem :( Thanks for your answers anyway

Comment: Please show the code that produces the error.

Comment: What is the error further down? How are you "checking" the value?

Comment: Nah something else is going on. A bit more code please.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - unforunately its not my code that produces the error, its when the app sends the object to a web service i.e. in the .NET magic code. The error is that the numeric value assigned to the variable `priceTypeB` must be an enum instead.

Comment: @DavidM - "checking the value" by setting a breakpoint and inspecting the variable by hovering the mouse over it

Comment: Well, an enum is nothing more than an integer, that you need to know. I can't comment on the rest, because you don't show any code.

Comment: So is your web service proxy code up to date? Is it implicitly casting the enum to an int because it believes this is what the web service is expecting? Try updating the reference to the web service.

Comment: @jimbo: Some users have some time trying to help; Can't you provide with the faulty line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when you check the value of priceTypeB it still shows an int

No idea how you are checking this value and where why you are seeing an `int` but the following check works perfectly fine:

```
public enum ePriceType
{
    Fixed = 1,
    Variable = 2
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int priceTypeA = 2;
        ePriceType priceTypeB = (ePriceType)priceTypeA;
        if (priceTypeB == ePriceType.Variable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Variable");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `No idea how you are checking this value and where ` - I added a break point and inspected the value from there :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class EnumProvider
{
   public enum ePriceType{
  Fixed = 1,
  Variable = 2
}

var a = Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumProvider.ePriceType), 1);
```

here a would be "Fixed"

Comment: Why wrap the enum in the class?

Comment: not necessary to wrap it in a class, we can also put it on same class